# Using X.509 certificate with OpenSSL in iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, openssl, x509, crt

I'm trying to figure out how to use the self compiled OpenSSL API to load an existing X.509 certificate (.crt) which I have included in Xcode's project structure.

I need a X509 object (from OpenSSL x509.h) which should be created/loaded from an existing file. Including the header works fine but I really can't find a way to load an existing certificate... There are sooo many methods in the x509.h but no sufficient documentation.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've read the character data into a `char* s`, something like

```
  BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)s, -1);
  X509* cert = 0;
  PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, &cert, 0, NULL);
  ...
  X509_free(cert);
  BIO_free(bio);
```